# QML: Why my buttons at the bottom are under the lower Android button bar, before creen rotation

Tags: android, qt, user-interface, qml, screen-orientation

In the code below, the row of buttons shows behing the Android lower bar of button (triangle, circle, square). When I rotate, everything is fine. When I rotate back, everything is fine too.

So it is only the first time that something goes wrong.

Any idea ?

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Item {
    property alias unit_add: unit_add

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableHeight

    ListView {
       (...)
    }

    Row {
        id: buttons
        width: parent.width
        height: 43
        visible: true
        spacing: 16
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Button {
            id: unit_add
            text: qsTr("Add")
        }

        Button {
            id: unit_delete
            text: qsTr("Delete")
        }

        Button {
            id: unit_edit
            text: qsTr("Edit")
        }
    }
}
```